# list of logged in unique users in linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh, uniq

I am working in linux environment as a non root user. I am using users command to get the logged in users

```
users
```

But it returns the user names multiple times because multiple shells are created with same login. Is there any way to print the unique user list using users commad.
Even i tried by

```
users | sort -u
```

Still it  returns the user names multiple times.

Answer (score 4):

Try with this -
`who| awk '{print $1}'|sort -u`

Answer (score 2):

```
users | sort -u
```

> Still it returns the user names multiple times.

Of course. `sort` is line based, and `users` only prints a single line.

What you want is to just look at the first word per line before `sort -u` in `who` output:

```
$ who|cut -f 1 -d " "|sort -u
barney
fred
wilma
```

or

```
$ who|sed 's/ .*//' |sort -u
barney
fred
wilma
```

However, if you are interested in some of the actual lines output by `who` you can also use

```
$ who|sort -u -k 1,1
barney  pts/23       Aug 26 10:11 (:5.0)
fred    pts/3        Jun 11 18:38 (:6.0)
wilma   pts/0        Jul 31 07:29 (:3.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this command: `who | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort | uniq`

You can use `w` command to get the list of logged in users and the details

Answer (score 1):

This one is a bit shorter:

```
users | tr ' '  '\n' | sort -u
```